# In a APIGatewayProxyEvent, what field will give me the URL?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to read [through the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format) and looking at the [types](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/index.d.ts):

```
export interface APIGatewayProxyEvent {
    body: string | null;
    headers: { [name: string]: string };
    multiValueHeaders: { [name: string]: string[] };
    httpMethod: string;
    isBase64Encoded: boolean;
    path: string;
    pathParameters: { [name: string]: string } | null;
    queryStringParameters: { [name: string]: string } | null;
    multiValueQueryStringParameters: { [name: string]: string[] } | null;
    stageVariables: { [name: string]: string } | null;
    requestContext: APIGatewayEventRequestContext;
    resource: string;
}
```

I can't tell how to get the full URL of the initial request. Can someone shed some light here perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`path` will give you everything except the domain itself. You should be able to get the domain from the `Host` entry in `multiValueHeaders` or `headers`.

Comment: FYI `this.event.multiValueHeaders["Host"]` returns something like `123456.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` if its the API gateway url that you are after.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone lands here looking for the domain of the *origin* of the request, as I did, it's available via

`event.multiValueHeaders['origin']`